How to blender 2 textures using BlenderKit
Is it possible I can mix 2 different textures using Blenderkit on an object?
When I use the find material option, I can drag/drop one material at a time, which the materials are available in the Material Properties.
for demonstration purposes, I just used 2 random materials.


what about making a node group out of both materials without the material output node, then make a new material with these two nodegroups and use  a mix shader node to combine them?

Yes, this was a good option, I didn't know I can save node-groups using Blenderkit. Thanks for your help.

you are welcome

Just make a node group out of both materials without the material output node. Then make a new material with these two nodegroups and use a mix shader node to combine them.
